# How to replace elements within div on click using query?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 separate div classes called demo-heart and demo-coal.  The functionality I am trying to enable:  when the user clicks on the fa-heart icon, it turns into fa-coal.  When the user clicks on the fa-coal, it turns into fa-heart.

```
<div class = "demo-heart">
    <a href = "#" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></i>
    </a>
</div>

<div class = "demo-coal">
    <a href = "#" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-coal fa-3x"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is what I ahve so far and it doesn't seem to be working.  But I also want it to be able to switch back to the original fa-heart when the user clicks on it.  Any suggestions?

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){
        $(".demo-heart").html("<a href = '#'><i class='fa fa-coal fa-3x'></i></a>");
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Instead of replacing the content of (every) `div` element, just toggle the class of the and `i` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the inlined onclick handler, then use jQuery [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click) to register the click handler

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('.fa').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('fa-heart fa-coal')
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uE5ER/)

Comment: @TusharGupta yes a typo... fixed

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler solution is to have one HTML structure and toggle the class within it:

```
<div class="demo-heart">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-heart fa-3x"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
$('.demo-heart a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('i', this).toggleClass('fa-heart fa-coal');
});
```

Note that I removed the `onClick` attribute in favour of a cleaner jQuery event handler.